# Как заставить Visual Studio 2019 сохранять исходники в UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8, кодировка, visual-studio-2019

Собственно, перерыл все настройки, не могу найти. Сохранять файлы в `UTF-8` по-одному - не вариант. Подскажите.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279673/save-all-files-in-visual-studio-project-as-utf-8

Comment: @Dareten, это я уже видел. Неужели в супер современной `Visual Studio 2019` нет опции, которая позволяет указать, в какой кодировке сохранять все создаваемые исходные коды? То есть, мне нужно руками писать какой-то костыль?

Comment: К сожалению, такой опции нет. Можно использовать ForceUTF8.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.